# What equipment do I need to repeat outdoor wifi with my own ssid?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have 2.4ghz 24db parabolic wifi outdoor antenna and router Dlink dap 2020, which has detachable antennas and i have replaced one with it.

I am able to connect to network, but the mode Repeater does not let me to change my ssid and password, it has to be the same as root wifi.

I have seen some routers with WISP option, allowing the creation of custom siid while using existing wireless signalt, but they dont have detachable antennas.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser! There seems to be a close vote because it seems you're looking for a product recommendation (which is not a good question to ask as answers become outdated fast). Could you perhaps [edit] your question to focus more on what *kind* of devices (repeaters, switches, antennas) you need to achieve your goal (e.g. get a good Wifi signal at XXm from the router)? While you edit, could you also clarify what research you've done so far on how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need three separate devices:

1. an outdoor Wi-Fi "wireless bridge",
2. an Ethernet cable going from #1 to #3,
3. a standard indoor wireless router.

Wireless bridges are generally used in pairs with their own protocol, but they can usually serve or connect to standard Wi-Fi networks as well. (Some have a standard connection for an external antenna, others have an internal "patch" antenna that's good enough for several km.)